# one app on Google Play and App Store with different name and logo for different country

Tags: google-play, app-store

I wonder if there is a possibility to have one app on Google Play and App Store which displays different logo and name for different countries?
For example, for device in country A my app needs to displays logo A and name A.
And when device is in country B - logo B and name B.
Detecting the country could be based on Google Play / App Store settings.

As far as I see there is no possibility doing things like this, but maybe I just could not find it.